# Error on CommandBinding in Infragistics XamRichTextEditor

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

My Infragistics-Version is 15.1.20151.2188.

I'm trying to reproduce the sample from [Infragistics Sample Browser](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/wpf/richtext-editor/content-editing) which binds Infra-commands to buttons in a custom toolbar and linking them to a `XamRichTextEditor` like this:

```
<ig:XamRichTextEditor AllowDocumentViewSplitting="True" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
<ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Button Content="F" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="0,0,5,0">
        <ig:Commanding.Command>
            <igPrim:RichTextEditorCommandSource EventName="Click" CommandType="ToggleBoldFormatting" />
        </ig:Commanding.Command>
    </Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Here are the namespace definitions:

```
xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"  
xmlns:igPrim="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/primitives"
```

During design time I get the following error (crash at runtime is happening too) in Visual Studio:

> The specified value cannot be assinged. The following type was expected: 'CommandSource'

Here the screenshot:

[image: VS designer error]

I checked `RichTextEditorCommandSource` using Object Browser:

[image: Type is correct]

As you can see, `RichTextEditorCommandSource` inherits from `CommandSource`.

I guess I'm missing a reference or something like this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was that for some reason I had to re-reference `Infragistics.WPF4.v15.1.dll`. I have only one version installed on my system and yes I restartet the VS and made a clean rebuild before I placed the question. Strange.